# May I use fonts of other Linux distros on Debian with KDE Plasma(Wayland)?

Tags: debian, fonts, kde, desktop-customization, wayland

I'm using Debian-12(Bookworm), with KDE Plasma(Wayland) desktop env.
I found that there are many nice fonts on other Linux distros, and that they are used with KDE Plasma also, while they can **NOT** be installed with the official apt repository of Debian.

I'm wondering that "May I install/migrate those fonts into my Debian box?".

Thanks!

Comment: TTF is an universal format.

Comment: Are you concerned about licensing? You'd need to check the rules for the source of the files. AFAIK, most versions allow such usage. As stated above, it should be easy to add a TTF or OTF font: https://linuxiac.com/how-to-install-fonts-on-linux/